# Why there is NoClassDefFoundError with a class that exists?

Tags: android, kotlin, noclassdeffounderror

I experience a weird `NoClassDefFoundError`, because the "NoClassDefFound's class" exists:

[image]

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cn.dreamtobe.babyguard.b.a$e
       at cn.dreamtobe.babyguard.data.BabyGuardDatabase.repealLastAction(BabyGuardDatabase.kt:109)
       at cn.dreamtobe.babyguard.data.BabyGuardDatabase$show$1.onClick(BabyGuardDatabase.kt:192)
       at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$1.onClick(Snackbar.java:255)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)
       at android.view.View.onKeyUp(View.java:9893)
       at android.widget.TextView.onKeyUp(TextView.java:6201)
       at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2667)
       at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:9245)
```

#### But the class `cn.dreamtobe.babyguard.b.a$e` is exists:

[image]

#### Stack point:

**Proguard one**

[image]

**Source one**

[image]

Comment: Need more info: which type has `recordList`, where `removeIf` comes from and which `Predicate` does it accept.

Comment: @Miha_x64 thanks for your notice. `recordList = ArrayList<RecordModel>()` and `data class RecordModel(val id: Long, val event: Byte, val timestamp: Long) `.  `removeIf` is lambda syntax which is provided from `kotlin` lang,  and `Predicate` is generated by `kotlin compiler` you can checkout from **Stack point** I provided on content.

Answer (score 2):

`java.util.ArrayList#removeIf` method was added to ArrayList in Java 8, along with functional interfaces (e. g. Predicate). You can use `filterNot` from Kotlin instead.